# How to get all documets from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all documents from firestore. I tried to do this

```
const firestore = getFirestore()
firestore
  .collection('products')
  .limit(4)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SHOW', snapshot })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_ERROR', err })
  })
```

then i do this

```
case 'SHOW':
      console.log('SHow 4', action.snapshot.docs)
```

but as response i get this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUJtw.png)
How can i get the values of objects?

Comment: console.log('SHow 4', action.snapshot.docs) gave the result on image

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot):

> A `QuerySnapshot` contains zero or more `DocumentSnapshot` objects representing the results of a query.

You therefore have to loop over the `QuerySnapshot`, as follows:

```
case 'SHOW':
    action.snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
```

or, you loop in the callback function passed to the `then()` method:

```
firestore
  .collection('products')
  .limit(4)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        // do something
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {...});
```

---

You can also [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript) over the JavaScript Array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot` that you get with `action.snapshot.docs`.

For example:

```
for (doc in action.snapshot.docs) {
    console.log(doc.data());
}
```